# Digital Clock On Console Window

Tags: java, time, clock

Hi my Clock Code Just Show The Instant Time but How can I make it digital which will Change second , minute and hour in console.

I need the program just for console ...not with Applet.

my code is here:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss.SSS a");
        String today = formatter.format(date);      
        System.out.println("Today : " + today);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Timer such as a `java.util.Timer` object with a `TimerTask` object. The API and tutorials should help you with this. [Here's one](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Comment: Can you convert my code for digital clock?

Comment: `"Can you convert my code for digital clock?"` -- No. Please don't ask us to write your code for you. Please check the link and try to do this yourself. We're not here to do your homework or assignments for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss.SSS a");
                    String today = formatter.format(date);      
                    System.out.print("Today : " + today+"\r");
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception ex){}
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true){

                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                String realTime = Integer.toString(hour) + " : " + Integer.toString(minute) + " : " + Integer.toString(seconds);

                System.out.println(realTime);

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.getStackTrace;
                }
           }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

simple while loop is enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss.SSS a");
            String today = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.print("\rToday : " + today);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should work. However please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.